# Examples of very basic GIMP scripts?

Tags: gimp, batch-processing, script

I want to write some simple scripts to use in batch mode, such as doing a resolution resize, or converting from rgb to grayscale.

The old scripts repository seems to have been taken down. I am looking for the most basic, bare-bones scripts that work. If these already exist, there's no need for me to reinvent the wheel!

I have read in the procedure browser how to get the functions I want, but the scripting language is not familiar to me yet. Are there any examples of super basic functions collected anywhere?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are various scripts available at http://gimphelp.org - I'm not affiliated with this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your Gimp scripts in Python. Python support is built-in since Gimp 2.8.

An example of a batch Python script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560

However, most simple image editing is better done with tools like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php). For instance, my script to resize pictures to 1200px, with a little boost in the saturation and some light sharpening:

```
for f in "$dir/"*.JPG; 
do
    convert "$f" -modulate 100,120  -geometry 3000 -sharpen 0x1.0 -quality 85 "$dir/$(basename "$f" .JPG).jpg"
done
```

(this is a bash script, of course on Windows you could do that in a .BAT or Powershell script).